# How to display a div based on a drop down selection

Tags: php, jquery, html

I've searched for a specific solution but cant seem to find the answer I'm looking for.
I'm developing a CMS system that selects a pre-developed module for each section.

When a user selects a module from the first dropdown list (select id='section1'), a list of properties will display
for this module.  When a user selects a module from the second dropdown list (select id='section2') the properties of that module should display.  There are 5 dropdown lists to choose from, each with the same options.  The problem I'm having is that when the first selection is made, the properties display all good and well.  But when the second drop down list is selected, the first selection's set of properties are replaced by the corresponding div of the second selection.

What I need is for the div of first selection to display even after the second selection is chosen.
So the properties for both modules should display.  When the module in the first option is changed, then so should the div displaying it's properties. Please help.  I know this is done with some jquery but I dont know how to manipulate the code to do what I need

Example:

```
<select id="section1"><option>Please Select</option>
<option value="1">Module 1</option>
<option value="2">Module 2</option>
<option value="3">Module 3</option></select>

<select id="section2"><option>Please Select</option>
<option value="1">Module 1</option>
<option value="2">Module 2</option>
<option value="3">Module 3</option></select>

<div id="module1" class="page" style="display:none;">Module 1 Properties</div>
<div id="module2" class="page" style="display:none;">Module 2 Properties</div>
<div id="module3" class="page" style="display:none;">Module 3 Properties</div>
```

The pattern repeats for each section, Like I mentioned, there are 5 sections, but I'll get the idea if you could help me with 2 sections.

The jquery that I'm using is:

```
$(function() {
$('#section1').change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (val) {
        $('div:not(#module' + val + ')').slideUp();
        $('#module' + val).slideDown();
    } else {
        $('div').slideDown();
    }
});
});

$(function() {
$('#section2').change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (val) {
        $('div:not(#module' + val + ')').slideUp();
        $('#module' + val).slideDown();
    } else {
        $('div').slideDown();
    }
});
});
```

Comment: It would be great if you created a JsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) or a CodePen (http://codepen.io/pen/) to show the behaviour of your code

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I added the code to jsFille http://jsfiddle.net/H37eb/.

Comment: it added the new module as it should, but if I change the option in section 1, it adds another module to section 1 instead of replacing it. When I change an option in section 2, it replaces the existing option, whether it is in section 1 or 2. Basically section should only display the module selected. If the module is changed in section 1, then so should its properties. Same goes for section 2. I'm sure there's a simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
$('div:not(#module' + val + ')').slideUp();
```

will hide all divs that isn't connected to the dropdown that is selected. This will cause the "Module 1"-div to hide when you are selecting in the "Module 2"-dropdown.

Try and remove that, I can't test it for the moment.

Comment: I uploaded the Jsfiddle script for you.  Removing the line of code that you suggested is almost what I need

Comment: Ok, what functionality is missing from what you want to achieve?

Comment: Thank you for the response.  When module1 is changed, then so should its properties.  With that line gone, it adds a new module if module 1 is changed, instead of replacing it with the new selected module.  Would it be possible to have the id names as the module names instead of 1 2 3 4?  It would also be ideal if 2 modules could be the same.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/hc6sh/1/

```
$('select option').click(function(){
    var num = $(this).index()
    var num =  '#module'+num
 // alert(num)
    $('.page').slideUp();
     $(num).slideDown();
});
```

Try this one

Comment: I updated the jsfiddle script to add ajaz.googlrapis reference to see if it will work, but the script doesn't work with or without those lines [link](http://jsfiddle.net/hc6sh/2/)

Comment: What did you added ? I have added already jQuery from cdn , My links working fine

Comment: I only added the ajaz.googlrapis reference in the top, otherwise it wont work as far as I understand.

Comment: Please see the left panel of the jsfiddle , You can see jquery file there

Comment: If I click on any of the drop down menus, no results are produced.